# finding xpath for elements in applications built on angularjs

Tags: angularjs, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The application under test is built on angular because of which the xpaths are failing to locate the element . I am using selenium web diver for automating the tests and google chrome browser.

Can anybody kindly specify how to break down angularjs components to basic html elements while creating the xpath or any other way i can adapt to find the exact element on the page.

Any link or path or tips to follow.

I have searched a lot but no luck till now.

Comment: What selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: test scripts are written in java. MA using testng with Maven, selenium version 2.49

Comment: thx alecxe. i upvoted your answer.

Comment: I am going through tutorials ..to learn protractor ..but i am scare that i dont know much about javascript.. if its a problem..or knowing core java is enough for protractor. :(

Answer (score 4):

Starting with covering some general concerns.

When testing AngularJS applications, the timing issues are usually the most common - this is partially why we have tools like [`Protractor`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) built mainly to test AngularJS applications. What makes it unique is that it works in sync with Angular, knowing when it is ready to be interacted with. It also provide AngularJS specific locators which makes locating elements much easier, samples:

```
element.all(by.repeater("item in items"));
element(by.binding("mybinding"));
element(by.model("mymodel"));
```

If you can, you should consider switching to `Protractor` - the test flow is natural - almost no explicit waits, a lot of convenient syntactic sugar and much more element-locating options.

If not, you can still use Angular-specific attributes to locate elements, examples:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@ng-repeat='item in items']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-binding='mybinding']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-model='mymodel']"));
```

Though, as usual, you should prefer to use `id`s, classes and other "data-oriented" attributes.

Things can easily go wrong with the above sample expressions - imagine web developers add a ["tracking"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) to the repeater, or rename the `ng-repeater` to `data-ng-repeater`.

As a side note, using Angular specific things like `ng-*` attributes in your tests, would make the test codebase tight to this specific technology used to build the application under test. It is not necessarily a bad thing but you should keep it in mind.

Comment: In protractor the scripting will be done in Java ?  is it a free tool?

Comment: @user3499450 it is a wrapper around WebDriverJS - javascript selenium bindings. Sure, it is free and open-source.

Comment: @user3499450 Actually, if this answer is useful to you, you should not only upvote it, but also accept it. Thanks.